После удаления дефолтных razor страниц в maui blazor перестает видеть папки
содержимое _imports.razor

файловая система

После удаления стандартных Razor-страниц, система не обнаруживает даже саму папку. Аналогичная ситуация происходит при создании новых папок. Как можно решить данную проблему? Существуют ли методы удаления компонентов, которые не повредят файловую систему? выдает ошибку Тип или имя пространства имен "Pages" не существует в пространстве имен "PraktikaMAUI.Components" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку)

«дефолтный razor страниц» - это на каком языке?
